# Error Migrating Android Project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, migrate

I'm working with old `android` project which is in `Eclipse`. I want to migrate to `Android` `Studio` for better support. I have use import function but have this error. Anyway to solve the probplem and make successful migration? Any help is much appreciate! Thanks

```
* Project singpost2013:/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/Android/singpost2013/project.properties:
Library reference ../../../../Documents/Android_SDK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib could not be found
Path is /Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/Android/singpost2013/../../../../Documents/Android_SDK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib which resolves to /Volumes/Data/Documents/Android_SDK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

This is my `project.properties` file

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../../../Documents/Android_SDK/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=../SPCaptureActivity
android.library.reference.3=../../../../Documents/Android_SDK/facebook-android-sdk-3.20.0/facebook
```

This is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: You may make your job finished faster creating AndroidStudio project using some auto-generated one, instead handling rather poor import feature. Adding files, changing project related files can be much easier to solve.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Can You give a bit more detail about the recommended way. I am not as familiar to Eclipse

Comment: Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Export from Eclipse

1.Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).

2.In Eclipse, select File > Export.

3.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.

4.Select the projects you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

Your selected projects remain in the same location but now contain a build.gradle file and are ready for Android Studio.

> Import into Android Studio

1.In Android Studio, select File > Import Project.

2.Locate a project you exported from Eclipse, select the project's root directory and click OK.

3.Select Create project from existing sources and click Next.

4.Follow the walk-through to complete the import process.

for more info

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html#overview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. do you have a link for eclipse and how to upgrade to version 22? (Sorry I not familiar with Eclipse before) only use Android studio

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh.. no actually i am also working with Android studio for a long time. Well i'm glad that my answer helped u :)